# PHP socket error Permission denied on Linux

Tags: php, linux, sockets

I have installed php 5.4.13 on Linux 2.6.34.

I have make simple client/server page using socket but it did not work on it.

It give permission denied error

Below is my php code

```
if (false == ($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))  // create socket 
{
   $stringData= date("D M d, Y g:i A"). " socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br>";
   echo $stringData;
}
else
{
    $timeout = array('sec'=>5,'usec'=>500000);
    socket_set_option($socket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,$timeout);

    if(false==($result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port)))
    {
        $stringData= date("D M d, Y g:i A"). " socket_connect() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br>";
        echo $stringData;
        socket_close($socket);
    }
    else
    {
        $stringData= date("D M d, Y g:i A"). " Socket connected succefully <br>";
        echo $stringData;

        if(false==(socket_write($socket, $command, strlen($command))))
        {
            $stringData= date("D M d, Y g:i A"). " socket_write() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br>";
            echo $stringData;
            socket_close($socket);
        }
        else
        {
            if(false===($cmd = socket_read ($socket, 65536)))
            {
                //10060 for windows and 11 for linux

              if(10060!=socket_last_error() && 11!=socket_last_error())
              {
                $stringData= date("D M d, Y g:i A"). " socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br>";
                echo $stringData;
                socket_close($socket);

              }
              switch(socket_select($r = array($socket), $w = array($socket), $f = array($socket), 5))
              {
                       case 2:
                               $refused=1;  
                               break;
              }
              if($refused==1)
              {
                $stringData= date("D M d, Y g:i A"). " socket_read() failed: reason: Connection Refused <br>";
                $ourFileHandle = fopen(SOCKET_LOG, 'a');
                echo $stringData;
                socket_close($socket);

              }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<pre>".html_entity_decode(print_r($cmd,true))."</pre>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code work fine on command prompt but it gives error Permission denied when page open from any browser.

Command of run php from terminal : `/usr/local/rootfs/php5/bin/php /www/socket_client.php`

Comment: What is the operational system? At some OSs only superadmins can bind to TCP ports bellow 1024.

Comment: we have received permission denied error while creating socket using socket_create() function..

Comment: I am running PHP on Arm-linux (Amlogic processor) board with kernel 2.6.34 version.

Comment: I guess it is not a distro with SE enabled by default, then...

Comment: I didn't get your point... distro means distribution SE in linux kernel or something else????

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux - there are directives in SE that would prevent non-white-listed applications to open sockets.

Comment: So by enabling this SE linux option from linux kernel, this issue can be solved ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31560/discussion-between-paulo-scardine-and-harry)

Answer (score 13):

Check your **php.ini** settings for the parameter "**safe_mode**". It should be "**Off**".

Another problem could be caused by "selinux" that is blocking your mod_php (apache process) from connecting via socket.
In this case:

```
# check if it's enabled:
/usr/sbin/sestatus -v
to add the connecting rule:
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

If you want to disable it completely:

```
setenforce 0
```

Also, for debug reasons, disable any security module on apache/PHP. For example try to disable [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) if it's running.

Comment: safe_mode option has already off by default... we don't have access to add selinux utilities using which we can set httpd environment variable.

Comment: We have also tried all the way to solve above issue except SElinux enable option which you are telling. Do you have other idea regarding permission to create socket or something else using which we can solve this issue?

Comment: No sir. I think it's SELinux that it's doing its security job

Comment: I have found something new related to user permission which can not allow to create socket from web interface. I can run php process from command promt with root user and can able to create socket successfully without any failure cases.

Comment: Then, I have created one non-root user and login into that user and tried to run socket PHP file but at that time it also not allow to create socket on terminal using command prompt.

Comment: so the main issue is regarding user and group permission while creating socket in PHP.

Comment: I have also change user and group to root user in httpd.conf file and start httpd process again but it also fails to start that process and gives warning to not to start that process with root user.

Comment: So, Do you have any idea regarding user permission to solve above issue?

Comment: Please let me know if you have any clue regarding user permission or any thing else in configuration file of httpd to solve above permission denied issue while creating socket..

Comment: Apache cannot run with "root" in "User" and "Group" directives. Try to raise PHP log verbosity in your php.ini

Comment: Log is already enabled in php.ini. But still i can not get any Logs related to socket or any other error logs in error logs of PHP.

Comment: Is there any other solution to solve above issue? Now, we have to solve this problem any way. Please suggest if you have any solution regarding user permission for socket programming in httpd process.

Comment: Is there any one can able to give my answer regarding user permission while creating sockets for httpd process???

Comment: try to temporary lower down apache maxclients setting to 1, then use "strace" command to try to figure out what's happening on your apache child process.

Comment: I have already debug using strace command which gives me following debug message while debugging child php process.

Comment: open("/ecommander/www/config/lang_default_full.php", O_RDONLY) = 14
fstat64(14, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=42350, ...}) = 0
fstat64(14, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=42350, ...}) = 0
fstat64(14, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=42350, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 42350, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 14, 0) = 0x412f9000
munmap(0x412f9000, 42350)               = 0
close(14)                               = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
chdir("/")                              = 0

Comment: socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
chdir("/")                              = 0

Comment: so it means we can not create socket without root user in PHP. Right?

Comment: I continue to suspect that it's SELinux dropping your socket() syscall.

Comment: but i can create socket from root user. so that is the problem regarding user permission while creating socket from PHP application.

Comment: As i have toled you before that there is no any support for SElinux in my board. so i want to solve this user permission issue without using SElinux.

Comment: I have already checked /var/log/messages as well as /var/log/messages but still there is no any log message related to socket operation failed due to user permission denied while creating socket using php binary on command prompt as well as from web interface.

Comment: The issue has been solved.. Thanks all for supporting me to debug this issue.

Comment: I have change socket configuration in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have nothing to do with PHP but with the permissions of the Apache web server (httpd).

I tried to fix the permission issue, but was not yet succesful.

If I disable the user switching in httpd.conf, my (Unix socket) connection works. However, this is only a quick development workaround **is not the final solution**, since the whole httpd runs as root this way.

```
#User _www
#Group _www
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

```
   <?php
   fsockopen('udp://192.168.1.255', 7, $errno, $errstr, 2);
   ?>
```

**Warning:** fsockopen(): unable to connect to udp://192.168.1.255:7 (Permission denied) in /var/www/html/udp.php on line 1

**Fatal error:** Uncaught Exception: Cannot open UDP socket: Permission denied in

php.ini if the server let's you change this configuration:

```
allow_url_fopen = On      // Was On
allow_url_include = Off   // On Didn't change the problem
```

Terminal check Firewall:

```
ufw status
Status: Inaktiv

/usr/sbin/sestatus -v
SELinux status:        disabled
```

Solution:

Broadcasting to **192.168.1.255** is not allowed, I changed it to the according IP address, i.e. 192.168.1.24

OR

By default broadcasts are disabled for sockeds. The socket_set_option command enables broadcast messages.

The follwoing script on the official PHP site:

```
<?php
# Wake on LAN - (c) HotKey (at SPR dot AT), upgraded by Murzik <tomurzik@inbox.ru>

flush();

function WakeOnLan($addr, $mac)
{
$addr_byte = explode(':', $mac);
$hw_addr = '';

for ($a=0; $a < 6; $a++) $hw_addr .= chr(hexdec($addr_byte[$a]));

$msg = chr(255).chr(255).chr(255).chr(255).chr(255).chr(255);

for ($a = 1; $a <= 16; $a++) $msg .= $hw_addr;

// send it to the broadcast address using UDP
// SQL_BROADCAST option isn't help!!
$s = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
if ($s == false)
{
echo "Error creating socket!\n";
echo "Error code is '".socket_last_error($s)."' - " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($s));
}
else
{
// setting a broadcast option to socket:
$opt_ret = socket_set_option($s, 1, 6, TRUE);
if($opt_ret < 0)
{
echo "setsockopt() failed, error: " . strerror($opt_ret) . "\n";
}
$e = socket_sendto($s, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, $addr, 2050);
echo $e;
socket_close($s);
echo "Magic Packet sent (".$e.") to ".$addr.", MAC=".$mac;
}
}

#WakeOnLan('yourIPorDomain.dyndns.org', 'your:MAC:address');
#WakeOnLan('192.168.0.2', '00:30:84:2A:90:42');
#WakeOnLan('192.168.1.2', '00:05:1C:10:04:05');

//if you have switch or other routing devices in LAN, sendign to
// the local IP isn't helps! you need send to the broadcast address like this:
WakeOnLan('192.168.0.255', 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx');
```

hth someone

Additional Information:

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fsockopen.php

[fsockopen() enabling it in PHP.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583787/fsockopen-enabling-it-in-php-ini)

https://serverfault.com/questions/371000/how-to-enable-fsockopen-function-in-php

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=919407

https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=39154

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the .sock file didn't have enough permission for the user running php (apache).

Was easier to fix.