# fsockopen() enabling it in PHP.ini

Tags: php, fsockopen, php-ini

in my PHP.ini file, I have this:
allow_url_fopen = On

it appears that is how to enable fsockopen()
But is that accurate?

Because my API is saying invalid key, when I have verified it is accurate, the people that gave me the key, said typically it is because the host has disabled fsockopen(), they also told me to whitelist some IP addresses of theirs for fsockopen(), how/where do I do that? is it in PHP.ini?

I have Cpanel which has the MultiPHP INI editor... so I checked in there and allow_url_fopen is set to On

But I don't see fsockopen() so I'm not sure if that is how to enable it or not.

Thanks,
-Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the way to enable it but PHP config has various levels.

If you are on shared hosting it is possible that you are using a php.ini in your user folder but this function has been disabled by the host at the core config level.
If this is the case you need to speak with your hosting provider.

You can easily check if it is enabled by viewing phpinfo

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Put this in a file on your server and access the page in a browser.

Comment: Thanks will do that.